# django-1.10 still contains deprecated and removed features

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, virtualenv

I am trying to run an existing django app. The app has been built in django-1.10. I set up a new virtualenv and installed the requirements and everything. However, I get errors like the following:

`from django.utils import importlib
ImportError: cannot import name importlib`

Now, the above is from the following source - `.virtualenvs/crowd/lib/python2.7/site-packages/account/conf.py`

When I manually fix the `conf.py` file, I still keep getting errors to fix either `deprecated` or `removed` features from older django versions.

Any idea as to how to fix this? I thought the purpose of working in `virtualenvs` was to avoid such errors.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**This is how the question is different: Even after I fix the importlib import statement, it keeps giving me errors like that of the usage of SubFieldBase and so on.**

Comment: That file (`account/conf.py`) seems to be included with [`pinax`](https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts/blob/master/account/conf.py), not Django core. Try upgrading your `django-user-accounts` package to a more recent version if it doesn't break existing functionality.

Comment: Thanks so much Selcuk! This fixed the problem.

Comment: Please don't edit a solution into your question. Instead, [add an answer and accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Done @Chris, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not with the Django-core but with `django-user-accounts` app that was included with `pinax`. Upgrading the `django-user-accounts` app fixed the issue.

Thanks to @Selcuk for the solution.